# redirect page after jquery submit using header() function on another page using php

Tags: php, jquery

i have this login form

```html
<form autocomplete="off" id="login_form">
    <div class="login-wrapper">
        <input required type="text" class="login-input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
        <span class="fas fa-envelope mail_name-email"></span>
        <span class="err_output err_email"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="login-wrapper">
        <input required type="password" class="login-input" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="password">
        <span class="fas fa-lock pwd_password"></span>
        <span class="err_output err_pwd"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="login_btn" id="login_btn" name="login" value="log in">
</form>
```

the submission is handled using jquery, like so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("submit", "#login_form", function() {
        Login();
        //send values to post
        const mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
        const pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./inc/login.php",
            data: {
              email: mail,
              password: pwd
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

so it works well but i wanted to do all the validation on the serverside particluarly in the login.php file included in the url within the jquery code because the data entered is sensitive and i cannot just redirect usin javascript. So even before i started the validation i tried a redirect to another page after the form was submitted but it wouldn't work, i tried `header("Location: ../main.php")` and `echo "<script>location='../dashboard.php'</script>";` but on the console all i saw was this

```js
jquery.js:9837 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/My%20portfolio/admin/inc/login".
```

i have even included an action attribute on my form pointing to the action page but it doesn't work, this is the only way i can proceed with validation otherwise i am stuck, i dont know what's wrong

Comment: If you're looking for server-side validation and want to redirect the user, why are you using AJAX? Can't you submit to the same page, validate and if everything is ok, redirect the user through PHP?

Comment: even then it doesnt redirect,

Comment: Well, can you show what you tried without AJAX? And what error you got when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a redirect in PHP on an ajax call. You need to return something to the JS page and redirect from there. For example, your PHP can return a json object with the status and the URL to forward to.

You can output something like this:

```
{
    "status" : "success",
    "url" : "http://www.example.com/url-to-redirect"
}
```

Or if it fails

```
{
    "status" : "error",
    "message" : "Error message to show"
}
```

Then in your javascript, check for the answer and validate the status

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./inc/login.php",
  data: {
    email: mail,
    password: pwd
  },
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function( data ) {
    if (data.status === "success") {
        window.location.href = data.url;
    }
    else if (data.status === "error") {
        alert(data.message);
    }
});
```

In your PHP script you need to output something like an array.

So in your PHP validation, if everything is validated, you can simply do

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'url' => 'http://www.example.com/url-to-redirect'));
```

But if it fails:

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error message to show'));
```

I suggest you read more on `json_encode` and `ajax` calls with PHP.

Comment: so how do i go about creating and returning the json objects in php